# AMPScript custom attribute row insert DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, insert

I'm trying to insert data from one data extension, which contains an XML, into a new data extension. This XML contains order information and my script writes this into the target data extension based on the products in the order / XML. This target data extension uses GUID as primary key so that works fine. After that, the automation runs to insert the data from that data extension into an archive data extension. Here the primary keys are Ordernumber and ProductID. This step in the automation gives me the following error: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key."

I can't find why there's a duplicate primary key. Does anyone know where it's going wrong? This is my script:

```
%%[ 

SET @SFCC_OrdersDE = "SFCC_Orders_Huisnrinhaal"
SET @OutputDE = "SFCC_OrderLines_Huisnrinhaal"
SET @LookupRowNr = 1
SET @Add = 1
SET @SiteID = lookup(@SFCC_OrdersDE,"SiteID","RowNr",@LookupRowNr)
SET @Rows = LookupRows(@SFCC_OrdersDE,"SiteID", @SiteID) 
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

IF @rowCount >= 1 THEN
    FOR @Counter = 1 TO @rowCount DO 

   SET @orderxml = lookup(@SFCC_OrdersDE,"OrderAsXML","RowNr",@LookupRowNr)
   SET @productRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@orderxml, "/order/product-lineitems/product-lineitem", 0)
   SET @ordernumber = Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@orderxml, "/order/original-order-no", 0), 1), "Value")
   
      for @j = 1 to RowCount(@productRows) do
                              SET @productXML = Concat("<product>", Field(Row(@productRows, @j), "XML"), "</product>")
                              SET @productShipmentId = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "product/shipment-id", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @GUID = GUID()
                              SET @productName = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/product-name", 0), 1), "Value"))

                              SET @productQty = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/quantity", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productPrice = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/net-price", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productTax = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/tax", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productGrossPrice = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/gross-price", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productBasePrice = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/base-price", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productTaxBasis = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/tax-basis", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productPosition = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/position", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productTaxRate = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/tax-rate", 0), 1), "Value"))
                              SET @productGift = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/gift", 0), 1), "Value")) 
                              
                              
  SET @CustomAttRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/custom-attributes/custom-attribute", 0)
      SET @CustomAttRowCount = RowCount(@CustomAttRows)

IF @CustomAttRowCount > 0 then
           SET @attrSuffix = '_att'        
           FOR @f = 1 TO @CustomAttRowCount DO

              set @row = Row(@CustomAttRows, @f)
              set @custAttr = Field(@row, 'Value')

              set @attrId = Field(@row, Concat('attribute-id', @attrSuffix))

              IF (@attrId == 'miraklSellerName') THEN
                SET @seller = @custAttr
              ENDIF    

              
              IF (@attrId == 'miraklOperatorProductID') THEN
                SET @MiraklProductID = @custAttr
              ENDIF   
              
              
            next @f
        ENDIF  
        
     IF not empty(@MiraklProductID) then
     SET @productID = @MiraklProductID
     ELSE
     SET @productId = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "/product/product-id", 0), 1), "Value"))
     ENDIF

           InsertDE(@OutputDE,
                              "productName",@productName,
                              "productID",@productID,
                              "productQty",@productQty,
                              "productPrice",@productPrice,
                              "productTax",@productTax,
                              "productGrossPrice",@productGrossPrice,
                              "productBasePrice",@productBasePrice,
                              "productTaxBasis",@productTaxBasis,
                              "productPosition",@productPosition,
                              "productTaxRate",@productTaxRate,                                                                                   "productGift",@productGift,
                              "productShipmentID",@productShipmentID,
                              "GUID",@GUID,
                              "ordernumber",@ordernumber,
                              "seller",@seller)
           
     next @j
     

SET @LookupRowNr = Add(@LookupRowNr,@Add)

 NEXT @Counter
 
ENDIF



]%%
```

Comment: Why don't you make GUID  also a part of the primary key set in the archive DE? so that you have three PKs, ordernr, productId and GUID. Since GUID alone would be unique, the combination for sure will be as well.

Comment: @JonasLamberty in that case it will write duplicates into the archive and that's not what we want. The combination of Ordernumber and ProductID is unique. It should not be possible to have duplicates, but the script is making duplicates. I need to fix something in the script so that it will not make duplicates.